# Run jQuery function immediately after an animate

Tags: jquery

im using the following JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edddotcom/7NQKU/1/

I'm using a callback function to change the background of the text immediately after the image is clicked,

The  is the sibling of the  so i was hoping i could just use .sibling() but it doesnt work, what am i doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
     <img src="http://cloudsmaker.com/hipsterwall/img/salto-al-norte.jpg" height="100%">
         <span>TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: block;
    width: 900px;
    height: 116px;
    background-color: red;
}
span {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    max-height: 100%;
}
img {
    float: left;
    height:100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //ON CLICK
    $("img").toggle(function () { //fired the first time
        $(this).parent().animate({
            //FIRSTCLICK COMMAND
            height: "232px"
        },function(){
            $(this).sibling().css("background-color","yellow");
        });

    }, function () { // fired the second time 
        $(this).parent().animate({
            //SECONDCLICKCOMMAND
            height: "116px"
        },function(){
            $(this).sibling().css("background-color","white");
        });

    });

});
```

removing the .sibling() part makes the  background change which also confused me.
How can i make it so only the text background changes?

Comment: you do know `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` is deprecated?

Comment: im using jQuery 1.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're trying to call is `.siblings()`, not `.sibling()`.

That would at least fix the console errors (you *did* look in the error console, didn't you?)

However since you're animating the container `<div>` ( i.e. `$('img').parent()` ) you actually need to change the span which is the *child* of that `div`.

```
$(this).children('span').css("background-color","yellow");
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/758FD/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a `sibling()` method, I guess what you're looking for is `next()`:

```
$(this).next().css("background-color","white");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `this` may now be the `parent` - that is, the `<div>`, which means `siblings()`won't work - you should use `children()`